# Is it possible to send POST request to Flash?

Tags: php, python, flash, file-upload, upload

I'm trying to make uploaded.net file uploader using python. I understand that uploading is just sending a POST request with the info needed, but in uploaded.net there's a flash file uploader:

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="misc/uploader.swf" width="100%" 
    height="100%" style="undefined" id="yuigen1" name="yuigen1" bgcolor="#ffffff" 
quality="high" allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="transparent" menu="false" 
flashvars="allowedDomain=uploaded.net&amp;elementID=yuigen1&amp;
        eventHandler=YAHOO.widget.FlashAdapter.eventHandler">
```

The flash uploader is: misc/uploader.swf.
How can I make the uploader work without a form?

Comment: Flash is client side so how do you imagine "send POST request to Flash"?

Comment: I really don't know anything about flash, my knowledge concerning requests at general is basic too.

Comment: I think you need to recreate that Flash (swf) app as a Python app. You cannot "send" file data into Flash. The user must select a file by choice. It's a security thing. Even if you did send it, how do you run the swf function for uploading? See?, can't be done.